# Makefile: Generate list with subdirectories

Tags: recursion, makefile

Let's suppose I have this directory structure:

```
-src
  |
  |-- subdir1
  |
  |
  |-- subdir2
  |      |
  |      |-- subdir3
```

I want to generate automatically a variable that finds the name of each subdir.

So something like:

```
BASE_DIR = src
# magic_recursive_wildcard_here := ...
DIRS = $(call magic_recursive_wildcard_here)

all:
    @echo dirs: $(DIRS)
```

And I want the output from all to be:

```
dirs: src subdir1 subdir2 subdir3
```

Is there any way to do that?

**EDIT:** If possible, I need a solution that works on both windows and Unix.

**EDIT 27/4/2015:** I tried Chnossos's answer and the output is this:

```
[21:59:27] ~\Desktop\makefileproj\src> make -d
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-pc-mingw32
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile `makefile'...
CreateProcess(NULL,CHDIR,...)
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, CHDIR, ...) failed.
CreateProcess(F:\Programs\CmdTools\coreutils\bin\DIR.exe,DIR /A:D /B /S .,...)
DIR: /A\:D: No such file or directory
DIR: /B: No such file or directory
DIR: /S: No such file or directory
Main thread handle = 0x000000e0
.: dira dirb Makefile
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file `makefile'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for `makefile'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.o'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.c'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.cc'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.cpp'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.p'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.f'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.r'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.s'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.mod'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.sh'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile,v'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile,v'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `s.makefile'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.makefile'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.o'.
  Looking for a rule with intermediate file `makefile.o'.
   Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.c'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.cc'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.cpp'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.p'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.f'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.r'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.s'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.mod'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.o,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.o,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `s.makefile.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.o'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.makefile.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.c'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `makefile.c'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.y'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.l'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.w'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.w'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.c,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.c,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.c'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `s.makefile.c'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.makefile.c'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.y'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file `makefile.y'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.y'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.y,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.y'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.y,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.y'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.y'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.y'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `s.makefile.y'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.y'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.makefile.y'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.l'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file `makefile.l'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.l'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.l,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.l'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.l,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.l'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.l'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.l'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `s.makefile.l'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.l'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.makefile.l'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.w'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file `makefile.w'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.w,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.w,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.w'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `s.makefile.w'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.w'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.makefile.w'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
    Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `makefile.w'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.cc'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `makefile.cc'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.cc'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.cc,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.cc'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.cc,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.cc'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.cc'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.cc'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `s.makefile.cc'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.cc'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.makefile.cc'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.cpp'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `makefile.cpp'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.cpp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.cpp,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.cpp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.cpp,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.cpp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.cpp'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.cpp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `s.makefile.cpp'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.cpp'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.makefile.cpp'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.p'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `makefile.p'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.web'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.p'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.p,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.p'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.p,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.p'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.p'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.p'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `s.makefile.p'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.p'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.makefile.p'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.web'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file `makefile.web'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.web'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.web,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.web'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.web,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.web'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.web'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.web'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `s.makefile.web'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.web'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.makefile.web'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.f'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `makefile.f'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.r'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.f'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.f,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.f'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.f,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.f'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.f'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.f'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `s.makefile.f'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.f'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.makefile.f'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.r'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file `makefile.r'.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
     Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `makefile.l'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.r'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.r,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.r'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.r,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.r'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.r'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.r'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `s.makefile.r'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.r'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.makefile.r'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
   Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `makefile.r'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.s'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `makefile.s'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.s'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.s,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.s'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.s,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.s'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.s'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.s'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `s.makefile.s'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.s'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.makefile.s'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.mod'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `makefile.mod'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.mod,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.mod,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.mod'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `s.makefile.mod'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.mod'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.makefile.mod'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `makefile.c'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `makefile.cc'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `makefile.cpp'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `makefile.p'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `makefile.f'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `makefile.r'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `makefile.s'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `makefile.mod'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.sh'.
  Looking for a rule with intermediate file `makefile.sh'.
   Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.sh'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `makefile.sh,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.sh'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.sh,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.sh'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/makefile.sh'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.sh'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `s.makefile.sh'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `makefile.sh'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.makefile.sh'.
  No implicit rule found for `makefile'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file `makefile'.
 No need to remake target `makefile'.
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file `all'.
 File `all' does not exist.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `all'.
Must remake target `all'.
Successfully remade target file `all'.
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Comment: What make are you using on Windows? If you are getting GNU make from cygwin, then the shell-based solution should still work. If you are using Microsoft's nmake, something different would be required.

Comment: It would work if he was running it from the cygwin shell. Not if he was running it from cmd.exe even if cygwin was installed (unless he put the cygwin stuff in his normal PATH.

Comment: I am trying to make my Makefile as generic as it gets. The shell-based solution would work fine for unix but is there a workaround or another approach for windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your edit, you basically have 2 solutions :

1. Use a linux shell under Windows and use `$(shell find $(BASE_DIR) -type d)`.
2. Use a condition on the OS you're running on :

   ```perl
   BASE_DIR := .

   ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
   DIRS := $(patsubst $(shell CHDIR )\\%,%,$(shell DIR /A:D /B /S $(BASE_DIR)))
   else
   DIRS := $(shell find $(BASE_DIR) -type d)
   endif

   $(info $(DIRS)) # print the variable

   .PHONY: all

   all:
   ```

Note that the space after `CHDIR` in `$(shell CHDIR )` is **mandatory**.

Comment: The command works on cmd alone but in Makefile I get this error: `process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, CHDIR, ...) failed.
DIR: /a\:d: No such file or directory
DIR: /b: No such file or directory
DIR: /s: No such file or directory
Dirs: src: dira  dirb`

Comment: Did you try to start make from a cmd.exe shell ?

Comment: Yes I run make from cmd.exe and I have also added this line in my makefile `SHELL = C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`

Comment: You should remove this line. Which make system are you running ? Simply pasting my code and printing `$(DIRS)` should work.

Comment: Even with this line removed it doesn't work. The first thing I tried is pasting your code (you miss a parenthesis to close patsubst btw).
The output from `make --version` is `GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-pc-mingw32`

Comment: I've edited my answer to correct this and try to understand what your problem really is here, you should try to run the same command as me and edit your question to add the informations printed.

Comment: I edited my post to include the output you asked for. I copied your code snippet directly into a Makefile and I run `make -d`

Comment: Where does that make executable comes from ? I think the problem lies here.

Comment: To be honest, I do not remember. It is a tweaked version I've found years ago. You think the problem is with my make?

Comment: It is the only thing that comes to my mind right now, considering the logs ... Try installing this version of MinGW and using its make executable : http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.9.2/threads-posix/dwarf/i686-4.9.2-release-posix-dwarf-rt_v4-rev2.7z/download

Comment: Well I tried it with MinGw's make.exe and I get this: `C:\Users\TheCrafter\Desktop\makefileproj\src>make
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, CHDIR, ...) failed.
make: makefile:6: pipe: No error
C:\Users\TheCrafter\Desktop\makefileproj\src\dira C:\Users\TheCrafter\Desktop\ma
kefileproj\src\dirb C:\Users\TheCrafter\Desktop\makefileproj\src\dira\diradira
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.`
It seems it has a problem with `$(shell CHDIR)`

Comment: It appears that if I change `$(shell CHDIR)` with `$(shell pwd)` everything works fine.

Comment: Yeah it is like make is not picking up the Windows' cmd but another one. Also, do notice that the space **after** `CHDIR` in `$(shell CHDIR )` is **mandatory**.

Comment: It is mandatory? Why is that? By the way in my code I have it with space just like yours. I just pasted wrong in my comment.

Comment: I can't explain this behavior. All I can say is that if I remove that space, I get the same result as you pasted with the new Make. Can you this time run `make -p` and add it to your question ?

Comment: It won't be necessary. I resolved the problem. Apparently I did not use the right dir. Turns out I did not use the native dir command. I had somewhere hidden in my path a custom dir.exe which apparently is not working so well. I don't know if I must be happy or suicide with a heavyweight facepalm.

Comment: At least you found it out :)
I've edited my answer to remove the debugging part.

Answer (score 1):

John Graham-Cunning wrote this neat [recursive wildcard](http://blog.jgc.org/2011/07/gnu-make-recursive-wildcard-function.html) function for make:

```
rwildcard=$(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2)
  $(filter $(subst *,%,$2),$d))
```

But I don't think that can do files vs. directories.

The only other solution I have is to shell out to `find` for this.

```
dirs := $(shell find '$(BASE_DIR)' -type d)
```

As Marc Fraioli points out if you want just the bare directory names in the variable then you want:

```
dirs := $(notdir $(shell find '$(BASE_DIR)' -type d))
```

For Windows this *might* work. I tested the `dir` command but not how make handles it.

```
dirs := $(notdir $(shell dir /s /b /ad $(BASE_DIR)))
```

How you determine which platform you are on to control which you use is a different question but there are a number of ways to do that.

Comment: Yeah I thought of using the shell too but will it work on windows? I don't think so!

Comment: Yeah, I almost added that caveat to my answer figuring that might be why you asked the question this way. I'm sure there is a comparable Windows answer for this I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try this:

```
BASE_DIR = src
DIRS = $(shell find $(BASE_DIR) -type d -exec basename {} \;)

all:
    @echo dirs: $(DIRS)
```

running:

```
$ ls -lR src
src:
total 8
drwxrwxr-x. 2 mfraioli mfraioli 4096 Apr 24 07:41 subdir1
drwxrwxr-x. 3 mfraioli mfraioli 4096 Apr 24 07:41 subdir2

src/subdir1:
total 0

src/subdir2:
total 4
drwxrwxr-x. 2 mfraioli mfraioli 4096 Apr 24 07:41 subdir3

src/subdir2/subdir3:
total 0
$ make
dirs: src subdir1 subdir2 subdir3
```

Comment: Yeah but that will not work on Windows. I just updated my question I've forgotten to add I wanted this for windows too.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old entry but thought I'd add my two-cents to it.
The way I did it in my personal projects is as follows for both Linux and Windows compiles:

```
ifeq ($(OS), Windows_NT)
DIRS := $(shell powershell 'Get-ChildItem -Path $(SRC_DIR) -Directory -Recurse | Resolve-Path -Relative')
else
DIRS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIR)/* -type d)
endif
```

^^^ Note: The reason I did `$(SRC_DIR)/*` instead of just `$(SRC_DIR)` for the `find` command is to avoid having `src/` show up in the list since I usually only keep `main.cpp` there and all my other code in sub-directories.